# HTML Form action tag. Calling a parent relative URL

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup a HTML form (Actually `.jsp` in the context of a Spring-MVC Application).

Assuming I am at the URL:

```
example.com/first/second
```

and I want to call an action to

```
example.com/post
```

What should the Action look like?

I expected this to work:

```
<form:form method="post" action="../post">
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: try to remove non valid ":form" part and use `<form method="post" action="../post">`

Comment: Are you asking how to reference the parent directory, or the "root" directory? That is, do you always want to refer to `example.com/post`, or would you want to call `example.com/first/post` if the local path was `example.com/first/second/third`?

Comment: @antejan: I am using this .jsp in a Spring MVC-Application. Here you will need to set the forms like: <form:form>

Comment: @DwightDeGroff Acutally this won't matter in my case. But I would be interessted in both, if possible ;)

Comment: Can you look at rendered html and give us what browser gets?

Comment: As @antejan suggested: you say "this doesn't work". What are your exact symptoms? Does it work if you specify an absolute path?

Comment: @antejan If you are still interessted, but I fixed the Problem as it seems. The `<form:form method="post" action="../post">`, works correct, but I made a mistake in my App, so the data was handled the wrong way. Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Relative path to `post` in the parent directory: `... action="../post"`

Relative path to `post` in the root directory: `... action="/post"`

Comment: Yep, found it out ;) Thanks