# form action does not contain original url in ie 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using this plugin for my file upload.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

In my html, I have:

```
<form id="importForm" name="Import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="import-input" id="importInput" type="file" />
            <button id="importBtn" class="btn btn-large" style="margin-top:10px" >Import</button>
        </form>
```

Then when Import is pressed, I call:

```
handleImportBtn(event) {
                var successCallback: (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXhr: JQueryXHR) => void = this.handleResponse;
                var options = {
                    url: "import/upload",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: successCallback
                };
                this.$(this.ui.importForm).ajaxForm(options);
```

This form is called from a url that looks something like:

```
mysite/area/
```

In FF and chrome, it does the right thing and `mysite/area/import/upload` gets hit.  In IE however, this is not the case.  Instead,

`mysite/import/upload` gets hit.  The relative path of the url is non-existent in IE 9.

Why does this happen?  And what can I do to get this to work in IE 9? :-\  Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure why it happens..try using absolute url

Comment: @charlietfl Hm, when I put in the absolute url, I get a 301 from both FF and IE....

Comment: something funny happening in server routing for that to show  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: will form sbmit through browser default without using ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl No, if I just put in `action="import/upload"` in my form and leave the url attribute in my ajax call blank, it still does the same thing.

Comment: is there a `<meta>` BASE tag in page?

Comment: @charlietfl no i'm not sure where that would be set.  i'm just starting on a web project.

Comment: `,meta` can see in browser `view source`, will be in head...sounds like you have routing problem...using a backend framework?

Comment: but...it does work in some browsers correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41449/discussion-between-crystal-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the absolute url didn't work for me either.  I was getting a 301 error.  After searching more for some ideas like at this post ([HTML Form action tag. Calling a parent relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363641/html-form-action-tag-calling-a-parent-relative-url)), I came up with this which works.

```
url: "../myArea/import/upload"
```